# Data leveling UI suggestions

Tags: gui-design, info-visualisation, data-tables, sliders, categorization

I m here looking for suggestions and design idea if someone can help please, Basically i m working on a screen that should display a lot of data defined by levels. Lets say we have a City with its data and for each city we have towns with its data and each town we have schools with each data and for each school we have lists on different categories Teachers, Students, Classes, Rules, Open times, Amenities. My issue is that we have a lot of data such city can have 100 towns and town can have 100 school and each list inside the school can have 20 entry. I was thinking to use the slides ([link of the idea](https://www.figma.com/file/TVr1QK8QErufBvgNOcj1IM/City-schools?node-id=0%3A1)), but with this number of components, the screen will be overcharged. Any ideas or suggestions?

[image: data vis using slider]

Comment: Please add inline images, as this well help others with a similar ux problem they're trying to solve who will come across this question at a later date.

Comment: Yes you are right, i ve just done it. Thanks for the remark.

Comment: Interaction design depends on users' goals. Please provide user scenarios to make it more clear what task(s) you want to solve.

Comment: Is there some reason you started with slides instead of a filter/sort bar? To me that seems like the answer but I'm not sure if I'm missing something.

Comment: Is this a mobile application?

Comment: Hi guys, thanks all for the response, in fact the issue i have is that i need to get all the data in the same screen without any navigation. It should be a web app. For now i went for the crone tree with pop-ups. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**At first:** The Arrow down, arrow top, and arrow left are confusing to the user understand what will happen when click.

**Alternatives:** Certify that the navigation is simple and easy to understand using hierarchy level or some interactive navigation.

You can do it horizontal or vertical, you can add animation to hide or not the last level (and add a back button)... you have too many options. You will need to make some tests to ensure which is better for your user and your type os content.

**IMPORTANT:** Guarantee the user easily know what is a link to a page/content and what is a navigation link that will show another menu option.

See some examples:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Yes thats the thing, i went for a crone tree, hopefully it will be something good for users.